# What is sudo chmod -R 775

Tags: sudo, shared-hosting, suitecrm

I need to know what does the below ssh command does?

```
sudo chmod -R 775 cache custom modules themes data upload
```

I am using shared hosting with godaddy, and we do not have access to sudo on ssh.

I am manually setting the permissions to the folders via filezilla

I need to know if the above file permissions is recursive to the "folders and files" within those directories? or if it is "only for the folders" within that directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command recursively makes all permissions 775 on the files / directories which follow

775 is read write execute for user and group and read + execute for everyone else

So yes it's recursive looking at the command they really just mean all directories rather than all files and directories

Comment: Which means that i have to set 775 for "folders only" within the directory, and not "files and folders"

Comment: The command does both. My guess here is the intention is just directory. Directory needs the x permission to view the contents.

Comment: Alright. I will set the 755 for "folders only". If there is issues, i can again manually reset via filezilla to "files and folders" later.

Thanks a ton @exussum